# How to update acts_as_list using multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-list

I have a Rails 3.2 app that uses `acts_as_list` on two columns in the same model:

This is in the `costproject` model:

```
acts_as_list :column => :division_priority, :scope => :client
acts_as_list :column => :department_priority, :scope => :department
```

In have two separate views for prioritizing. One is a view for prioritising by division. A link called "TOP" will execute the following code in the `costprojects` controller:

```
  def divtop
    @costproject = Costproject.find(params[:id])
    @costproject.move_to_top
    redirect_to costprojects_index3_path
  end
```

How do I distinguish on the line `@costproject.move_to_top` that I'm using the `division_priority` and not the `department_priority`?

Thanks for the help!